# How can I associate multiple entries to another entry in another table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm creating a site where people can rent out their house. I currently have two tables in my database.

Properties
 - property_id
 - address
 - city

Amenities
 - amenity_id
 - amenity_name

The site admin has the ability to add amenities to the database. A landlord logs into the site, where they have the ability to choose which of the amenities their property has(ex: pets, furnished).

I'm trying to figure out a way to associate one or multiple of the amenities to one single property. I'm guessing I need a third table that will somehow keep track which amenities are associated with properties.

How can I associate multiple amenity_id's to one property_id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a PropertyAmenity table with simply two columns:

```
property_id
amenity_id
```

The primary key should be a composite of both property_id and amenity_id.  You might also want to add a user_id and update_date field is auditing is important.

This will allow you to associate a property to many amenities.

foreign key relationship should be between:

```
Properties.property_id and PropertyAmentity.property_id
Amentities.amenity_id and PropertyAmenity.amenity_id
```

Example:

```
Property:
property_id  address             city
100          Property 1 St.      NY
101          Property 2 St.      NY

Amenity:
amenity_id   amenity_name
100          Central Air
200          Swimming Pool

PropertyAmenity
property_id   amenity_id
100           100
100           200
101           100
```

In the above example, Property 1 has both central air and a swimming pool, while property 2 has just Central Air.

To select the the amenities for a given property you can write sql like:

```
Select a.* from Property p, PropertyAmenity pa, Amenity a
where p.property_id = pa.property_id
and pa.amenity_id = a.amenity_id
and p.property_id = 100
```

Comment: First off, thanks for helping! 

I sort of understand what you're saying, but I'm having difficulty visualizing it all. Could you please show me an example with values for the different tables, so I can see how they relate to each other? Also, what is the sql statement needed to SELECT all amenities for a specific property? I don't completely understand the code sample you provided.

Comment: Thanks for the great example! Is your code example php? I'm not sure I don't recognize some of the commands like the letters 'a', and 'pa'. What are those?

Comment: the example ishow sample data you would have in a table and the sql to select a property's amenities.  I believe this is what you asked for.